# Issues when including an existing library into c++ project

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am importing a library called libspatialindex from http://libspatialindex.github.com/ into my current project named "rtreelibrarytest" in netbeans. In order to import the same into netbeans I followed the following steps:

1. Using Options => Build => Linker => Libraries included the library files with extension '.a'.
2. Using File => Project Properties => Build => C++ Compiler => General => Include Directories (Included the directory)

Now when I build the project as well as the library. The library has been included in the project. I get the following error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../rtree/spatialindex-src-1.8.0/src/tprtree/.libs/librtree.a', needed by `dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/rtreelibrarytest'.  Stop.
```

I am not able to figure out as to what should now. Also I am a novice in c++. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `include` directory where your library file is. I suspect that this is your problem. You should only change the include directory to point at `include` directories, not libraries.

Your `1.)` step looks valid, your `2.)` appears invalid. You should, however, add the `library` path to the linker, if not already present.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response. How can I add library path to linker. 
Also I have included my entire directory in 2nd step. Sorry if my sentence looked a bit unintutive.

Comment: `Properties -> Build -> Linker -> Libraries -> Add Library File` should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response and help