# Issues with linking library C++

Tags: c++, c, netbeans

My problem is I am not able to include a library into my current project. [The way to include a library in netbeans into a project is to link it via linker to the project]. However, in my current project(which is written by another programmer who left the organization) the option of linker is not appearing. I have attached a screenshot.  I am faced with the issue that the option of linking the library via linker to my current project is not appearing in IDE. Can someone please please help me out. I'll be highly thankful to you for the same.

Please guide me as to how should I link the library to my project. I have really spent a lot of days doing it but I did not succeed. [image: screenshot]

Comment: Show the command line invoked by your interface.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'll surely show the command line. But I dont know how to do it (what should I do so that the command line appears)..can you please guide me...also thanks a lot for the reply :) Also I am really a newbee in this so please excuse

Comment: You are confusing headers and includes with library files and the linking process. Linking is invoked from the compiler you use (gcc i presume). Linking with gcc is a matter of passing the correct arguments and having the libraries in your system.
 I do not see why it would be different with netbeans. Have you tried passing the link flags for the libraries you use as an argument ?

Comment: @Alex Sorry buddy I have not tried that. But I dont know how to pass link flags for libraries as arguments. Can you please guide me. Also for linking the libraries in netbeans I am following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855379/issues-when-including-an-existing-library-into-c-project?rq=1

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Can you please give me clues...I'll myself google and show you the command line invoked by the interface..please help buddy..it's been days since I have been stuck with this.

Comment: which library are trying to link with?

Comment: @Alex I am trying to link libspatialindex

Comment: @Alex Thanks again buddy..you are a very helpful fellow. :)

Comment: @Keira Shaw, double check both your program and file permissions.

Comment: @VenomFangs How should I check that...please guide me..I am a novice at this..thanks for replying buddy. :)

Comment: @Keira Shaw, setting file permissions is well documented, please use google.

Comment: I cannot give any clue. I never used any IDE (like Netbeams) for compiling C++ code (I'm very happy with `M-x compile` under `emacs`). And I always have explicit `Makefile`-s in my code. So my hint is: stop using IDE and learn how to use command based tools (`g++`,`make`,....) like most free software do. You really need to understand what is actually happening. (the more I see IDE related questions, the more I feed that IDE are counter-productive).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only interesting in libspatialindex:

1. Make sure you have the appropriate files installed: try a `locate libspatialindex` and see where it is installed. You could have a *.a, *.so or similar extension. Note the path.
2. Go into your project root directory, i.e: /home/keira/netbeans/projects/myproject
3. Try: `gcc -i main.cpp -L/usr/lib/ -lspatialindex -o myfile`

Replace the -L/usr/lib with the actual location where you know the library is at.

The cxx link flag is usually the name of the library with an -l prefix. If for example the name found in the system is `libspatialindex.so` then its a good bet to try with `-lspatialindex`.

There is a way to find the actual flags on Debian & Ubuntu systems but I cannot atm remember it. Alternatively you can always look on google or read the library documentation.

When you usually see linker errors with undefined functions, etc, it means you're not linking, provided you have included the headers and they are found.

Now for Netbeans, I assume there is the option of passing extra arguments to the compiler. In this case, all you need is the `-lspatialindex` flag, provided Netbeans knows where to find the library and the headers. That is how it works in KDevelop and other IDE's I have used.

Alternatively if you want more control and more automation, you may want use a tool like cmake.

Comment: ..thanks for the help..I usually run the command in netbeans with " "${OUTPUT_PATH}" db myfile.txt". So should I include -"L/usr/lib/ -lspatialindex -o myfile" After that...please guide

Comment: you are on the right track...it is unable to find just the name i.e. lspatialindex...i dont know how to get that...should  -L/usr/lib be the location where the file .so file is or where the source files are because they are at different locations

Comment: @KeiraShaw Have you found the library in your system? Do you know where its located? Did you install it through aptitude or did you download it, build it and manually install it?